# How to remove an app from the Facebook App Center?

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-center

I have an iOS app that was approved for the Facebook App Center. Now I would like to remove the app from the Facebook App Center. How can I do that without deleting my app page?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Please goto **Facebook Settings** then goto **account settings** and then **click apps**
then you can **manage the applications** you subscribe earlier...